# What exactly are the rate limits for the web API?

Tags: spotify

What exactly are the rate limits for the Spotify Web API? I've read all the docs but I can't seem to find the EXACT numbers? Will they be different based on the implemented Auth flow? Active Users?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Looking at their [Rate-Limit](https://developer.spotify.com/documentation/web-api/#rate-limiting) docs, it says they tell you how long you must wait until you can make your next call if you make too many requests. If you use that, you can never have an error in your app based on rate limits. Wouldn't this solve your problem?

Comment: @AskYous Yes, this is true. However, I'd prefer to know what the exact numbers are, so I can efficiently design the application. I don't want users to have to wait to use a feature, due to a rate limit restriction. If that is the case I'd rather not incorporate Spotify into the app.

Comment: Got it. I guess just find a way to contact them. It's weird they don't have a contact section in their dev docs.

Comment: did you got a feedback here? how many request can we have per 30 seconds?